# Read global parameters from with pandas from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I often use python pandas to analyse measurment data from a lab. For example if I have some "global" parameters "a = 5.2e-3" and "b = 3.21e-5" which are valid for the series of measurement, where the value y is measured in dependence of x, but may be different for another series of measurement of x and y. The problem is that I have to define `a` and `b` inside of my python file like this:

```
import pandas as pd

a = 5.2e-3
b = 3.21e-5
d = pd.read_csv('mydata.dat')

def func(a,d):
  ##... calculates something from a and d
```

Where `mydata.dat` contains

```
x,y
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

However I want to define it inside of my data-file `mydata.dat`, something like this:

```
## Global parameters
a = 5.2e-3
b = 3.21e-5

## Measurement data
x,y
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

Surely I could write my a custom parser, but I am looking for an out of the box solution. Maybe the syntax may be a bit different, but short and elegant. One may even thinking about another library similar to pandas.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

> *".. Maybe the syntax may be a bit different, but short and elegant."*

IIUC, you can try something with the *builtin* module [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) :

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

cfg = ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True, default_section=None)
cfg.optionxform = str # case-sensitive keys
cfg.read("mydata.dat")

from io import StringIO
d = pd.read_csv(StringIO("\n".join(cfg["MEASUREMENTS"])))

def fn(d, a):
    return d.mul(float(a))

out = fn(d, cfg["GLOBALS"]["a"]) # or **cfg["GLOBALS"] if `fn` asks for a&b
```

Output :

```
print(out)

        x       y
0  0.0052  0.0104
1  0.0156  0.0208
2  0.0260  0.0312
```

Used input (*mydata.dat*) :

```
[GLOBALS]
a = 5.2e-3
b = 3.21e-5

[MEASUREMENTS]
x,y
1,2
3,4
5,6
```